# prove that |A| = $\aleph _0 $ for a set A which meets the following conditions:

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

given a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ which follows:

1) $\mathbb{N} \subseteq A$

2) $\forall x \in A \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \exists y\in A \ : y^n = +x \ or \ y^n = -x $

3)if a set $A'$ follows the conditions 1 and 2 than $A \subseteq A' $

show that $|A| = \aleph _0$.

---

thanks ahead.

Comment: Condition 2 is vacuous.  For x in A, take y = x, n = 1.

Comment: For 3, is the set A' a subset of R?   The only set that has 1,2, 3 is R.  The symbol i is the sqrt of -1.  The word I is pronoun for a person;  use it.

Comment: Was $A'\subseteq A$ a typo for $A\subseteq A'$? All three of your conditions are satisfied if $A=\mathbb R$ but $|\mathbb R|\ne\aleph_0.$

Comment: yes of course i changed it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $${\Bbb N}^{\frac{1}{k}} = \{ l^\frac{1}{k} \;|\; l \in \Bbb N\}$$ be the set of all k-th roots from the naturals which is obviously countable for all $k\in \Bbb N$ and $$A' = \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb N} {\Bbb N}^{\frac{1}{k}}$$ be the union of all those sets which is countable as a countable union of countable sets.

Then $A'$ fulfills 1.) and 2.) by definition because 1.) is clear by construction and for $x \in A'$ it has to hold $x\in {\Bbb N}^{\frac{1}{k}}$ for some $k$ hence $$x=l^\frac{1}{k}$$ for some $l,k \in \Bbb N$. Taking $$y = l^\frac{1}{kn} \in {\Bbb N}^{\frac{1}{kn}} \subseteq A'$$ gives us $$y^n = l^\frac{n}{kn} = l^\frac{1}{k} = x$$ as wanted.

Hence $A'$ fulfills 1.) & 2.) and is countable so we get as a result $$\Bbb N \subseteq A \subseteq A'$$ and $A$ is sandwiched by countable sets so it's countable itself.